# Clear set interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, setinterval

```
 setInterval(function hello() {
  console.log('hello world');
  return hello;
}(), 6000);
```

how I can clear the interval, I tried add var interval

```
var i =0;
var interval = setInterval(function hello() {
  console.log('world');
  if(++i == 3) clearInterval(interval);
  return hello;
}(), 5000);
```

But it didn't worked. thanks for your help.

Comment: `clearInterval()` definitely works. What makes you think it didn't?

Comment: Why are you only trying to clear the interval on every third iteration?

Comment: Define "*… it didn't worked*". What did you expect? What actually happened? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: The code runs and stops in chrome....not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @HawkenRives—it displays "world" 3 times at a 5 second interval, then quits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clearInterval() certainly works. You have error in the following line of code:

```
    }(), 5000);
   //^^ remove () as this is not IIFE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i =0;
var interval = setInterval(function hello() {
  console.log('world');
  if(++i == 3) clearInterval(interval);
  return hello;
}(), 5000); // notice those parenthesis
```

you are supposed to pass a handler to `setInterval()` not invoke it in place ,